# style-loader not working for Webpack2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I had simplified my webpack2 configuration. But still this is not working ( 
with no errors and warnings ).

#### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const svgDirs = [
  require.resolve('antd-mobile').replace(/warn\.js$/, ''),
  path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/svg'),
];

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', path.join(__dirname, 'src')],
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.js', '.json'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg)$/i,
        use: 'svg-sprite-loader',
        include: svgDirs,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      hash: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

I tired to log these styles out. But all empty objects!

```
import styles1 from './Styles1.less';
import styles2 from './Styles2.css';
console.log(styles1); // empty object!
console.log(styles2); // empty object!
<div className={styles1.class1}></div> // not working
```

Below is my `package.json` and `.babelrc` if you need to check out.

#### package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --hot --port 8000",
    "build": "webpack -p --progress --colors",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js src test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd-mobile": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.42.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.14.8",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.3",
    "postcss": "^5.2.17",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "postcss-pxtorem": "^4.0.0",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "^1.0.2",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",
    "redbox-react": "^1.3.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^0.3.1",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

#### .babelrc

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
      "plugins": [
        [
          "react-transform",
          {
            "transforms": [
              {
                "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
                "imports": ["react"],
                "locals": ["module"]
              }, {
                "transform": "react-transform-catch-errors",
                "imports": ["react", "redbox-react"]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        ["import", { "style": "css", "libraryName": "antd-mobile" }],
        ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `style-loader` works correctly, but it doesn't do what you think it does. All it does is inject your CSS into a `<style>` tag at runtime.

The actual issue is that you expect the imports to behave like [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), but you are not actually using CSS modules. With your current setup you can import the CSS and the classes will be available globally, so you use that class name on your element. For example:

```
import './Styles1.less';

<div className="class1">Hello World</div>
```

By enabling CSS modules (on the `css-loader`), you will receive an object with the class names mapped to the actual identifier of the class, when you import any CSS. You need to change the respective rules.

```
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: true,
        importLoaders: 1,
      },
    },
    'less-loader'
  ],
},
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: true,
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

With that you'll be able to use them as you wanted.

```
import styles1 from './Styles1.less';

<div className={styles1.class1}>Hello World</div>
```

The actual DOM element will look like this:

```
<div class="_3Rxg00d8E5vC1LOyJvBzl2">Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the output path in webpack config js

```js
{
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the "use" config instead of "loader/s"

```
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [{ loader: "style-loader" }, 
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "less-loader" }
         ],
  },
```

heres the reccomended usage of style-loader with webpack
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#recommended-configuration